# You don't have to stand over there!

Tags: riddle

> I am an anti-gravity device,
>
> I want to protect you from its flattening pull.
>
> I do not have potatoes,
>
> Those are for my siamese twins.

What am I?

Comment: errr....it was so scientific...until you got to line 3

Comment: @NL628 or the title...

Comment: I changed the title, it was too distracting.

Comment: is "it's" intentional, or it's a typo for "its"?

Comment: Thanks, it is a typo, I am going to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also be:

> A chair?

I am an anti-gravity device,

> It keeps you from falling to the ground

I want to protect you from it’s flattening pull.

> It cushions you

I do not have potatoes, Those are for my Siamese twins.

> 2+ chairs joined by the sides are a couch. "Couch Potatoes"

Comment: OK, let me give one more guess.  Added another answer to my first.

Comment: Congratulations! It is a chair! I hope you don't mind, I am trying to edit your answer. The way it is written, it looks like 'bones' is the answer instead of 'chair'.

Comment: @ErikGecas - Hey, beware spoilers in the comments! :)

Comment: No problem, approved the edit

Answer (score 6):

It is

> A bike tyre

I am an anti-gravity device

> The bike (and tyre) hold you off the ground

I want to protect you from it’s flattening pull.

> The tyre is built to resist going flat

I do not have potatoes

> A potato is a tuber.  No potatoes = tuberless (tubeless tyre)

Those are for my siamese twins.

> Two tyres (twins) on a bike

Comment: I like your answer, especially the part about tubers. The object I am describing has a 'siamese twin' version that is double in size yet maintains its function (this object is associated with potatoes).

Answer (score 1):

It is

> A satellite

I am an anti-gravity device

> Works using the opposing forces of gravity between it and the earth.

I want to protect you from it’s flattening pull.

> It uses its momentum to keep it from falling to earth.

I do not have potatoes

> Unmanned satellites have no environment for growing potatoes.

Those are for my Siamese twins.

> The manned satellite ISS, has [its own agricultural laboratory](https://www.nasa.gov/vision/earth/everydaylife/spacespuds.html) which astronauts test the growth of potatoes in antigravity - the first vegetable grown in space.

Comment: I am going to have to tell Idaho (the potato-state) that potatoes were the first food grown in space; they will probably put it on their license plates! I like your answer, but this object keeps YOU from flattening from gravity. (unless you are on a space station...or you might not be using this device right now...)

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> a bungee jump rope

I am an anti-gravity device,

> The rope pulls you in the opposite direction of gravity. → anti-gravity

I want to protect you from it’s flattening pull.

> The elasticity protects you from flattening against the ground.

I do not have potatoes,

> I have no idea about this one but I have the feeling it has something to do with the rope. (see next line)

Those are for my siamese twins.

> Siamese sounds like trapeze. Seamise twins refer to the two ropes that a trapeze is attached by.

Comment: I like your description of avoiding being flattened out. The object I am looking for has a very clear colloquial association with potatoes.